# CSS2 Diamond shape with image background

Tags: html, css

I would like to make a diamond shape with a image background. I can do it, the only problem is the image seems to rotate at the same time which i do not want. This also needs to work in ie8

fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/zangief007/2bft2rcx/1/

```css
#diamond {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background: purple;
    margin: 3px 0 0 30px;
    /* Rotate */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
         -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
    /* Rotate Origin */
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
       -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
        -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
         -o-transform-origin: 0 100%;
            transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the rotation and adding

```css
#diamond:before, #diamond:after{
    content: '';
    border: 80px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -80px;
    z-index: -1;
}
#diamond:before {
    border-right-color: #ccc;
    border-left: none;
    right: 50%;
}
#diamond:after {
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    border-right: none;
    left: 50%;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2bft2rcx/3/)